# Pandas evaluate based on value in other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
data=[{
    'structural_type': 1,
    'directors': 'Ertil Altanaj',
    'ft_score': 255.54696655273438,
}, {
    'structural_type': 1,
    'directors': 'Erbil Altanaj',
    'ft_score': 14.529092788696289,
}, {
    'structural_type': 1,
    'directors': 'Richard Klemann',
    'ft_score': 202.32211303710938,
}]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How would I get the index in decreasing order of the fts_score. For example, the answer would look like this:

```
   structural_type        directors    ft_score  ft_score_index
0                1    Ertil Altanaj  255.546967               1
1                1    Erbil Altanaj   14.529093               3
2                1  Richard Klemann  202.322113               2
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Pandas .rank() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

You can use pandas .rank() function on a column to get these indices, and pass in the parameter ascending=False to rank them in decreasing order

```
df["ft_score_index"] = df["ft_score"].rank(ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing using rank function of pandas:

```
df['ft_score_index'] = df['ft_score'].rank(ascending=False)
```